# Need to call static attributes "dynamically" on PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I'm having the following issue.

Inside my Banner class I have:

```
public static $flag_status = array(
                               'Unpublished'
                          ,    'Published'
                          );
```

Out of the Banner class, I have an array that contains the 'flag_status' value which represents the attribute on the Banner class.

Let's suppose that I'm getting this value from the array and storing on a variable like this:

```
$name_attr = 'flag_status';
```

I need to call:

```
Banner::$name_attr;
```

And it should return the same as calling:

```
Banner::$flag_status;
```

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two dollar signs:

```
Banner::$$name_attr;
```

Example:

```
class Foo {
    public static $flag_status = array( 'foo', 'bar' );
}

$name_attr = 'flag_status';

print_r(Foo::$$name_attr);
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this but it wouldn't work because It had a space before the string, but now it works! Thanks!

Comment: If this worked for you please mark it as correct so that others will know :-)

Comment: Ok! Done :) God bless you!